# Hive timestamp format?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Is there any specific timestamp format hive supports?

My spark job has a timestamp "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss" but while storing the same in hive the data is converting to null?

the hive table has the data type as timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can check [Hive Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-TimestampstimestampTimestamps)

Supports traditional UNIX timestamp with optional nanosecond precision.

Supported conversions:

- Integer numeric types: Interpreted as UNIX timestamp in seconds
- Floating point numeric types: Interpreted as UNIX timestamp in seconds with decimal precision
- Strings: JDBC compliant java.sql.Timestamp format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.fffffffff" (9 decimal place precision)

I think this is what applied to your case

Timestamps in text files have to use the format **yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.f...].** **If they are in another format, declare them as the appropriate type (INT, FLOAT, STRING, etc.) and use a UDF to convert them to timestamps.**

Answer (score 0):

One way (**end expensive one**) to do is to set  `mergeSchema` to `true`

Easier way is handling `null` in timestamp column with a **deafault** value like `coalesce(col("<spark_ts_column>"),lit("1970-01-01-00-00-00").cast(TimestampType))`

btw, the **format** of timestamp does not look standard , sample data/code would help.